# Delete path DCIM

Tags: android

I need to delete path DCIM internal in the Android.
I have this code

```
    File dir = new File("root path");
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(dir);
```

But FileUtils does not work.
Can anybody help me to write the correct code?

Comment: do you want to delete the DCIM folder itself or its content?

Comment: @Yirga is does not matter , any solution it will be great .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you cannot delete the DCIM folder because its a system folder but you can delete its contents using the following method.

```
public static boolean deleteDCIM(File dir) {

    String [] children = dir.list();
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < children.length ; i ++ )
    {
     File child =    new File( dir , children[i] );
     //if the child is a directory make a recursive call
     if(child.isDirectory()){
         deleteDCIM( child );
     }
     //else delete the child file 
     else{
    child.delete();
     }
    }
}
```

get the path using

```
String dir= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
```

Comment: **Yirga** I do not understand why my code is does not work ?
Code below .
 I'm new in Java , I worked in Xamarin .

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    File dir= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    deleteDCIM(dir);
}

public static void deleteDCIM(File dir) {
    String[] children = dir.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        File child = new File(dir, children[i]);
        //if the child is a directory make a recursive call
        if (child.isDirectory()) {
            deleteDCIM(child);
        }
        //else delete the child file
        else {
            child.delete();
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: what error are you getting are can you explain that please?

Comment: @ Yirga in the gradle console when I start is sent "Build Successful" , but in the Run very much errors and all "Fatal Exception" "at" very much processes . I think to all processes . What is can be ?

Comment: @Yirga I can not found solution , I need a way .

Comment: can you tell me your error or post the stack trace?